# Draw set mapping diagrams

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to draw some set mapping diagrams with LaTeX. Do you know any packages that can do this? I tried searching online but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Hi justo and [welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: @PolGab: Please edit your link. It's not clickable. (Well, I can click it but you know..)

Comment: The link @PolGab tried to insert is [http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino This is the correct link. Thank you for your correction.